# Error: Could not resolve 'myNewEntity' from state 'site'

Tags: jhipster

Since the current JHipster doesn't support an embedded object in an entity, I have to change the front end code as well as the back end after running "yo jhipster:entity myEntity". After changing related new created Javascript files, I get an error

```
Error: Could not resolve 'myNewEntity' from state 'site'
```

when I click the entity menu item under the "Entities". Due to this error, I can't do any manual tests on my project.

I only can find one entry with [the error](https://gitter.im/jhipster/generator-jhipster/archives/2015/06/15). My situation isn't in the product mode though.

How to solve this error?

Comment: I had same problem and finally this problem was because I forgot add myentitie.state.js in index.html , so I only had to add it and everything was ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you modified to the angular-ui router states that have been generated by jhipster:entity.

You should have a look at myEntity.js, it should define 4 states.
Then compare these names with the ui-sref of entities menu in navbar.html.

Another possibility is that you forgot to add or change the js scripts in index*;html and so your states are not defined.

Comment: Thanks very much for the information. I will look into once I get a new generated application up to the modification point.

Comment: Your accepted answer percentage rate being so low, I don't expect anything.

Comment: Hi Gael, sorry for this slow reply. I just finished the project generating process again last night. To my test so far, the problem doesn't occur this time. I don't notice anything I do differently in Javascript code thought.